# Symbolic link's not visible on Jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins

After upgrade Jenkins instance to version 2.387.1 (On Centos 7), I lost abillity to see in Jenkins browser symlinks created on job workspace.
After some research found that this was security feature - [link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.263/#SECURITY-1452).
I added to config mentioned in above link Java property: hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.allowSymlinkEscape=true

After that symlinks was visible, but only on master node, they are still not visible on agent's.

Update Java parameters according to Jenkins page. Would like ask If somebody know how to resolve it or of it possible resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but I fixed it by add hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.allowSymlinkEscape=true on CLI in Jenkins Agent. Set this on Jenkins Manager is useless.